# Could not find devise-1.4.6 in any of the sources

Tags: heroku, devise

I have installed devise 1.4.6 succesfully on my local development environment. I have this in my bundle file: gem 'devise'

But when I want to deploy it to heroku, it says "Could not find devise-1.4.6 in any of the sources". What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line just at the beginning of your Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
```

Heroku doesn't seem to have RubyGems in their list of sources for gems.

Alternatively you might want to execute `bundle update` to update your gems to the newest version (iirc, devise 1.4.7 is out) and then push to heroku again.

Comment: The source "http://rubygems.org" is already in my gemfile, but the bundle update command seems to solve it. Thanks!